# bower automatically update bower.json

Tags: bower

I run the following commands using bower 1.0.0:

```
mkdir testdir;cd testdir
bower init #accept defaults
bower install jquery -s  #the -s is supposed to cause update of bower.json
less bower.json
```

In bower.json I expect to see dependencies listed, but there are none.  What is going on?

NOTE: `bower install jquery --save` does work

NOTE:
The option I am referring to was documented through `bower help install`

```
**-S**, --save              Save installed packages into the project's bower.json dependencies
```

Comment: `bower help install`, `--save`, `--save-dev`

Comment: `bower help install` says both -s and --save should work equivalently.
I'm a bit offended at the suggestion that I did not look at the help... of course I did!  I suppose I will edit my question to emphasize that fact.

Comment: I'd appreciate removal of the down vote if that is why it was put there.

Comment: That was not my downvote http://clip2net.com/clip/m48912/1375130702-clip-4kb.png. With my bower installation (0.10.0) `-s` does nothing, just as you described. `--save`, however, works. Also, in my bower help -s is not listed at all!

Comment: If you happen to upgrade to 1.0.0 and see this issue let me know, please.  Perhaps I will file a bug report.

Comment: Seems like `-s` does not work in 1.0.0, but you still can use `--save`

Comment: The last edit is correcting the actual problem. It doesn't help such edit, @Heekei

Answer (score 380, accepted):

from bower help, save option has a capital S

```
-S, --save  Save installed packages into the project's bower.json dependencies
```

Comment: ok so why would I not want to save it to the dependencies json - I thought the whole idea of this is to track the package...what happens when you just install it ?

Comment: if you don't use the save flag, it'll just download the package you choose and put it under the bower packages folder, it's a good way of testing a package before setting it into stone.

Comment: @Gru if you test a package like that, how would you add the package to bower.json afterwards, when successfully tested? Manually?

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen I've just tried it and if you install the same package a second time with the save option it will add it to bower.json

Comment: @gru This is indeed useful. I'd be nicer if there was a --trial flag to keep it from being saved since, at least for me, saving to dependencies is more frequent than not.

Comment: yeah, as commented by @RobinvanBaalen, unless you're using something really well known (e.g. angular), one might end up doing a `bower install`, then playing a bit with the library, then if happy running it again with `bower -S install`. the other way round would be to run `bower -S install` immediately, and if not happy just delete the line corresponding to the installed package in `bower.json`