# How to update bower.json with installed packages from bower_components

Tags: bower

How to update `bower.json` with installed packages from `bower_components`?

`bower init` does not add all my installed packages into `bower.json`, some are obviously missing

`bower list` fails connecting to github on one package.

So whats the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Check this if help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865487/bower-automatically-update-bower-json and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279792/how-to-update-bower-json-with-installed-packages

Comment: Using `--save` installs the package and adds it to the file. But you cannot except people to run the installs again for every package... Using `bower list` as I wrote...

Comment: Yes, this has been answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26585444/228369

Answer (score 1):

Install all your new dependencies with `--save` tag. This will add them to 
your `bower.json` file automatically.

```
# e.g. bower install angular --save
bower install <package> --save
```

If you missed adding `save` tag you can just run bower init and it will generate a new `bower.json` using dependencies from existing bower_components folder.

```
bower init
```

Comment: The question is, how to do this after the fact

Comment: @chrismarx I think the second edit to this answer solves the issue doesn't?